# Converting byte-stream into numeric data-type

Tags: php, floating-point, 64-bit, integer, 32-bit

Let's say I have a byte-stream in which I know the location of a 64-bit value (a 64-bit nonce). The byte-order is Little-Endian. As PHP's integer data-type is limited to 32-bit (at least on 32-bit operating systems) how would I convert the byte-sequence into a PHP numeric representation (float would be sufficient I think)?

```
$serverChallenge = substr($bytes, 24, 8);
// $serverChallenge now contains the byte-sequence 
// of which I know that it's a 64-bit value
```

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56786533/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-float-in-php) is how to convert byte array into float in PHP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just looked up the code for `Zend_Crypt_Math_BigInteger_Bcmath` and `Zend_Crypt_Math_BigInteger_Gmp` which deals with this problem:

### Using BCmath (Big-Endian)

This is essentially the solution posted by [Chad Birch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726092/converting-byte-stream-into-numeric-data-type/726323#726323).

```
public static function bc_binaryToInteger($operand)
{
    $result = '0';
    while (strlen($operand)) {
        $ord = ord(substr($operand, 0, 1));
        $result = bcadd(bcmul($result, 256), $ord);
        $operand = substr($operand, 1);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

### Using GMP (Big-Endian)

Same algorithem - just different function names.

```
public static function gmp_binaryToInteger($operand)
{
    $result = '0';
    while (strlen($operand)) {
        $ord = ord(substr($operand, 0, 1));
        $result = gmp_add(gmp_mul($result, 256), $ord);
        $operand = substr($operand, 1);
    }
    return gmp_strval($result);
}
```

Changing the algorithem to use Litte-Endian byte-order is quite simple: just read the binary data from end to start:

### Using BCmath (Litte-Endian)

```
public static function bc_binaryToInteger($operand)
{
    // Just reverse the binray data
    $operand = strrev($operand);
    $result = '0';
    while (strlen($operand)) {
        $ord = ord(substr($operand, 0, 1));
        $result = bcadd(bcmul($result, 256), $ord);
        $operand = substr($operand, 1);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

### Using GMP (Litte-Endian)

```
public static function gmp_binaryToInteger($operand)
{
    // Just reverse the binray data
    $operand = strrev($operand);
    $result = '0';
    while (strlen($operand)) {
        $ord = ord(substr($operand, 0, 1));
        $result = gmp_add(gmp_mul($result, 256), $ord);
        $operand = substr($operand, 1);
    }
    return gmp_strval($result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a total hack, but it should do the job, assuming you have the BC Math functions that daemonmoi recommended:

```
$result = "0";
for ($i = strlen($serverChallenge) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--)
{
    $result = bcmul($result, 256); // shift result

    $nextByte = (string)(ord($serverChallenge[$i]));
    $result = bcadd($result, $nextByte);
}
```

Comment: Actually it really looks a little bit ugly, but it seems to be a viable solution.

Comment: Removed up-vote because the code is using Big-Endian byte-order. Still accepting the answer because it led me the right way.

Comment: Whoops, that was dumb of me, I'll switch it around. Glad it helped anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Two years late to the party, but if anyone still cares:
unpack is the built-in way to go here, you can unpack it as a couple of 32-bit ints, or as a double.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not quite the answer to the question, but check out [the BC Math functions](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) to handle big numbers.

Comment: Actually I know the BCMath extension but these functions won't be helpful because they need the integer-value as a string - but I only have a byte-stream which must be converted into something that PHP (or BCMath or GMP) can use as a number...