# Convert 8 bytes to a signed long (64 bit)

Tags: php, sockets, networking, 64-bit, binary

I'm reading 8 bytes from a socket in PHP, and want to transform them into a 64 bit signed integer.

- How can I do this in 64 bit PHP? `unpack` doesn't support 64 bit numbers
- In 32 bit PHP, is there a way to make it into a string that can be used by BCMath?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting byte-stream into numeric data-type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726092/converting-byte-stream-into-numeric-data-type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps *[Converting byte-stream into numeric data-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726092/converting-byte-stream-into-numeric-data-type)* will help...